# @Any: Not supported yet

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm working in a project that's already grown up, so I won't be able change any version of any of the used frameworks or libraries.

Actually, I had a particular situation that I managed to resolve with two entities and `@Inheritance`, `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue`. Now, I have an entity with references to both classes in the inheritance, like this:

```
@Entity
//Other annotations
public class A implements IA {
    //Class body
}

@Entity
//Other annotations
public class B extends A implements IB { //Note: `IB` extends `IA`.
    //Class body
}

@Entity
//Other annotations
public class Container {
    private IA object1;
    private IA object2;
}
```

The problem here is that I'm trying to use @Any annotation, because either `object1` and/or `object2` can be of type `A` or `B`. What I've done is this:

```
@Any(metaColumn=@Column(name="objectOneType", length=3),fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@AnyMetaDef(idType="long",metaType="string", metaValues={
        @MetaValue(targetEntity=A.class, value="A"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity=B.class, value="B")
    }
)
@JoinColumn(name = "relatedObjectId")
private IA object1;
```

As stated [here](http://javalabor.blogspot.com/2012/03/jpa-2-metamodels-and-hibernates-any.html), Hibernate's `@Any` annotation family has no counterpart in JPA 2 and, since I can't switch to Hibernate 4.1, I'm stuck here trying to figure out a way to make it work or what should I do to fix it.

A "not so elegant" way would be to create a new entity and copy the fields from A to B, erasing the inheritance and fixgin the particular cases.

Maybe, I'm losing some particular feature in JPA that I don't know yet, so I'm currently open to and thank any kind suggestion that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you need Any in the first place? A reference to an A can point to a B without needing to do anything, since B extends A.

Comment: Well, that would leave me with two A element and I'd have to figure out each kind... Now I wonder, if A has the ID as it does wouldn't that bring the A-only fields for a B object or would it do `A object1 = new B()` directly? Now that you mention it... I feel like I'm being kind of "overdefensive" here...

Comment: The type of both fields is IA, so you don't know which type it is anyway (A or B). B extends A, so B **is** an A. Although the type of the variable is IA, the actual type of the object could be A or B. And Hibernate will fill the reference with an instance of the appropriate concrete type all by itself.

Comment: Crystal Clear, Thank you. Care to post that as an answer? That's what I'm heading thowards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any `@Any` annotation. B extends A, so B `is` an A. So the following is sufficient:

```
public class Container {
    @ManyToOne
    private A object1;

    @ManyToOne
    private A object2;
}
```

(assuming the association is a ManyToOne. It could also be a OneToOne)

Hibernate will figure out the concrete type of both objects all by itself, and will initialize object1 and object2 with an instance of A or B.